# nested sql query to find the count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

1. A students table with data as rollno, batchids.
2. A batches table with batchid,courseid.

The batchids column of students table contains comma separated batchids of various courses student might be enrolled in. Now I want to get the count of students coursewise. Can someone help me?

So far I have reached

```
select * 
from students 
where batchids in (select id from batches where courseid=1)
```

This gives me a list of students in course with id '1'.

Comment: A comma separated list of batchids in the student table, that complicates things.  What is the relevance of courseid=1?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using - SQLServer, MySQL....?

Comment: Before proceeding you should fix your data model. A "*comma separated list of batchids*" is a very bad idea.

Comment: edited to answer your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use count().

```
Select count(*) 
from students 
where batchids in (select id from batches where courseid=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data correctly, you have something like:

students:  (s1, '1,2,3')

batchids: ('1,2,3', 1), ('1,2,3', 2), '1,2,3', 3)

Assuming this is correct, the comma delimited list is just a key into the batchids table.  So, to get the count for each course do a join:

```
select courseid, count(*)
from batches b join
     students s
     on b.studentid = s.studentid
group by courseid
```